# Adding random thickness around a mesh

Tags: modeling

So I'm trying to find a quick way to add random thickness, On the  image below I don't want the selected faces to move on the Z-Axis.
[image]

However I do want these faces below to Move along the X and Y Axis or normals.
[image]

I was hoping to use vertex groups combined with a modifier but I couldn't get what I wanted with simple deform and vertex groups. I just want a quick and effective way to move faces along their normal's to add random thickness in selected areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the object you have in the picture, you can add two displace modifiers with a noise or clouds texture. Set one to effect the Y direction and the other to effect the X direction. Make sure Space is set to global.

[image: Displace]

You might like the results better if you first made a flat, segmented  rectangle shape, then use a displace in only the x axis (Local Space this time), subdivide it, solidify it, and then use a curve modifier to modify the object like below. You can mess around with different displacement textures and amounts to get the look you're after.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to move the surface, click shift z. so it will only move in the x and y directions.

Comment: you can use the Proportional editing with Random along with the shift+z